# Xcode Simulator not working

Tags: xcode5, ios-simulator

I'm trying to use Xcode 5.1.1 to help develop an app, but I can't get the simulator to work properly. The app builds successfully, then an alert saying, "No application was specified" pops up. Then the simulator shows black with a gray bar at the bottom with a Safari icon - none of which has anything to do with our app. I know it isn't the code itself because it works fine on another computer. Any thoughts on what's going on and how I might fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Within the iPhone/iPad simulator, go to the top-menu and select "iOS Simulator" -> "Reset Content and Settings..."

Hopefully this will allow you to build as it seems the problem lies within your personal simulator rather than you code. Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a "build scheme" and that it is configured correctly, I found this thread on Apple support communities which seems to describe the same problem your facing.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/25459735#25459735

Comment: I found that thread as well, but don't think the resolution applies to my situation because the app I am building is not connected to Facebook in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that identity is set under the target, I was having the same issue setting the correct plist file fixed the issue.